# Stripe plugin having this issue

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, stripe

stipe payment form not working on checkout page [image: nto]

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the developer of the extension?

Comment: it's free version of extention.. no support

Comment: Which extension? Perhaps someone in the community will know it.

Comment: please try with another card number like : 4111 1111 1111 1111, than check it, hope its working for you.